# Mingw32 Cross Compiling Linux to Windows - configure: error: lacking proper OpenGL support

Tags: c, linux, windows, opengl, cross-compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mingw32 Cross Compiling Linux to Windows - configure: error: lacking proper OpenGL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185789/mingw32-cross-compiling-linux-to-windows-configure-error-lacking-proper-open)

I'm trying to cross compile source code of a 3D Linux game that incorporates among other things, OpenGL, over to Windows Using Mingw32. My devel box is loaded with fedora 12 and all the tools that I could imagine would be needed to cross compile. The project will configure make and install under Linux for Linux no problem. But when I try mingw32-configure, I get an OpenGL related error.

Here is a snippet of the command line output:

```
checking GL/gl.h usability... yes
checking GL/gl.h presence... yes
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for glEnable in -lGL... no
configure: error: lacking proper OpenGL support
```

I haven't found anything useful on other threads or on the web as none address this issue directly. Has anyone run into this before? How can I resolve it?

Comment: @genpfault: please don't vote to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one.  For the short period of time where this question existed and the other one didn't, it wasn't a duplicate, and so it shouldn't be closed as such.  Instead, vote to close the newer question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a funny problem with automake. There are two issues.

For one the configure script assumes the OpenGL library to be named just "GL" like it's the case on Linux. On Windows the name is "opengl32" (also for 64 bit builds).

The other problem is, that the configure script tries to do a runtime check of OpenGL is actually executable on the system by building test programs that each links to the one function being tested for and then executing them. This will of course fail, because on a Linux system there's no Windows OpenGL implementation (except if running this within WINE).

You need to rewrite your configure script to use "open32" as library name and for the test programs it would make sense to grab one of the Mesa builds for Windows carrying only the software rasterizer, so that the test executables actually pass the test.

---

On a side note I'd like point out that I hate the GNU autotools

Comment: I found that on newer Linux versions, the mingw32 executables installed by yum are now called i686-w64-mingw32-* instead of i686-pc-mingw32-* which can also cause this configuration check to fail. In my case (compiling Qt) it just happened that the first check that caused an abort was OpenGL, which brought me here. Symbolic links from the old names to the new was enough to fix the problem.